# Windows 10 reboots itself without any warning, but just once

Tags: windows-10, reboot

I'm facing a weird issue on my Windows 10 PC. Last weekend I reinstalled Windows to rollback from the latest Windows Insider build, so I didn't format all the drive but just did a fresh Windows installation. Since then, every time I power up the PC, it restarts itself without any previous warning within a couple of minutes -- just black screen and motherboard logo again. It could appear as an hardware issue, like a classical overheating or faulty RAM issue, but the curious fact is that once it rebooted then it goes on for hours without any further problem. Moreover, again, this strange behaviour only started since the reinstallation of Windows. Is there something I can do to track down the issue?

My specs:

- ASRock Z77-pro4 Motherboard
- CPU Intel Core i5-3450
- NVidia GTX 680 4gb
- 32gb (4x8gb) DDR3 Kingston
- Samsung SSD 850 EVO 1TB (Main HDD)
- Seagate ST1000DM003-9YN162 (Backup drive)

Thanks for any suggestion!

Comment: Assuming you have the system set up to NOT reboot on BSOD, can you trigger this happening by using a GPU stress test (e.g. furmark or similar?) If yes, then your PSU may be failing.

Comment: I disabled automatic reboot right now, since it was on by default; we'll see, anyway I see no log in the Event Viewer nor dump file, so I'm afraid it's not a BSOD. I also suspect isn't something GPU related: the reboot happens when I'm browsing, and hours of The Witcher 3 after that doesn't trigger any reboot...

Comment: I just resolved a PSU problem and it sounds exactly like you mention. I could play games for hours and then the next time I loaded the same game it would shut down. On Fallout 4 I could trigger it by enabling ssao, and avoid it by disabling ssao. Seemed like a software problem except for the shutdown. So I tested it by (dangerously) adding a jumpered 2nd PSU for the GPU PCI12v. Solved the whole thing

Comment: Obviously, I replaced the PSU once I diagnosed it. The thing is, straight shutdowns ought not happen, and if your MB is set to stay off on power loss, if it "goes  low and comes back on" it may be a protection mechanism.

Comment: Another little piece to the puzzle. I finally discovered some Log Viewer events: I have some Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power Event 41, with all EventData set to 0. Apparently this gives more credit to the PSU theory: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2028504 (Scenario 3)

Comment: I had that too. Basically a report of power failure after it came back up, but nothing to indicate a crash etc (no mindumps, no logs etc). My problem looked software at first, but after maybe 2 months, it was happening 5-6 times a day.

Comment: Ok... I'm almost convinced now. The fact that it reboots just once after I power it on from full powered off state could mean that starting from a cold condition it struggles more, while after the reboot it's somewhat already hot and can handle properly...

Comment: See if you have a second psu lying around or you can borrow one to test, preferably one with equal or greater wattage.

Comment: Unfortunately not, I don't have it. I'll buy the new one from Amazon, so I have 30 days to return it the issue persists.

Comment: Unfortunately I just changed the PSU but the error still persists...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By googling around I found [this post](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/4411-73-computer-reboots-minutes-runs) in which an user suggested to disable Fast Boot in Windows 10. I did so just to try, and I have to admit I've not had a reboot since then, and some days are passed already. Here are the steps to disable Fast Boot (or Hybrid Shutdown, as he calls it), but you can find them by just follow the link on the post I already linked here. They're written for Windows 8 applies to 10 as well:

> 1. Log on to Windows 8 computer with the administrator account on which Hybrid shutdown is to be disabled.
> 2. Click Desktop tile from the Start screen to go to the desktop screen.
> 3. Once on the desktop screen, hover mouse to the bottom right corner of the window.
> 4. From the displayed options, click Settings.
> 5. On the Settings pane, click Control Panel.
> 6. On the opened Control Panel window, click System and Security.
> 7. On the System and Security window, click Power Options from the right pane.
> 8. On the Power Options window, click Choose what the power buttons do option from the left pane.
> 9. On the System Settings window, click Change settings that are currently unavailable link to enable the advanced options.
> 10. From the enabled options under Shutdown settings section, uncheck Turn on fast startup (recommended) checkbox to disable Hybrid
>       Shutdown.
>
> Click Save changes button to save the modified settings. Close Power
>   Options window when done.
>
> Note: In order to re-enable the Hybrid Shutdown in Windows 8 computer
>   follow steps 1 to 9. On the step 10, check the Turn on fast startup
>   (recommended) checkbox and save the changes.

So, as it seems, it was a software issue, not an hardware one.