# Windows 10 is restarting suddenly and randomly

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, reboot, dell-inspiron

Since a few months ago (not sure if it was after the last Microsoft update), my Windows 10 laptop is restarting on its own without any warning, it was doing it once or twice a month only, but this last month, it's restarting every day.

I tried to manually update the drivers, but the problem is still here.

I searched all over the internet and it seems like many people are facing this problem, but I couldn't find a solution.

Laptop model and specs: Dell Inspiron 15R (N5110), i5-2450M, 8GB RAM DDR3, Nvidia 525M

Comment: What is the model of your laptop? What is the version of your Windows? What drivers have you tried to update? Do you get any error message?

Comment: Dell Inspiron N5110, i5, 8Go RAM DDR3, Nvidia 525M, 

Windows 10 (mentioned in the title)

Comment: What [edition*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_10_editions) of Windows 10 do you have? Repeating - What drivers have you tried to update? Error messages?

Comment: I used the device manager to see if Windows update has missed something, and I found some updates that did manually and weren't detected by Windows update, the major one is the Nvidia GC update. But this didn't help as it still restarting now

Comment: I have a Windows 10 Pro

Comment: Have you tried to remove the battery and run solely on power from a charger? Have you upgraded from Windows 7 or is it a clean Windows 10 install? Was the 8GB of RAM installed by default on your laptop or did you upgrade it yourself?

Comment: I didn't try that. It's a clean install. I added 4GB of RAM, but it was over a year ago.

Comment: Try setting active hours in Windows 10 as outlined over [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/264325/how-to-set-active-hours-so-windows-10-wont-restart-at-a-bad-time/).

Comment: @Don'tRoothereplz... the laptop has just done a restart even though this is set as an active hour, i don't think that this is the problem. The restarts as i said happen suddenly without any warning.

Comment: Could you include the log from Event Viewer? [Here](https://www.maketecheasier.com/see-pc-startup-and-shutdown-history-in-windows/) if you need help. Also, have you tried [this](http://superuser.com/a/1072249/573485) solution?

Comment: @Don'tRoothereplz... I tried your last solution to disable Fast Boot, once I did it the laptop was restarting every 10 minutes ! I booted with an Ubuntu CD to finish a work that was urgent, and the PC was working good. After that, I restarted the PC and logged into Windows, I re-enabled the Fast Boot and surprisingly it's not restarting (until now) and it has been more almost 12 hours of work. I will continue using my PC and I will post an update here.

Comment: @Don'tRoothereplz... it has been two weeks since the last restart of the PC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After months of searching, I found a reply somewhere that suggested to just ... disable fast boot on Windows 10 and it's working fine for me. Even formatting the PC didn't help.

Answer (score 2):

An automatic Restart when the system crashes is unforunately the default.  You can disable it by unchecking the box `Automatically restart` in the `Advanced` tab of `System Properties`, under `Startup and Recovery`.

Also make sure that `Write debugging information` is enabled with a setting of `Automatic memory dump` or something like that, and that `Write an event to system log` is checked.

[image]

Next you review the Windows system Event Logs via the Event Viewer app.  Look for `Error` and `Critical` entries for clues.

Next thing to do is install a Memory Dump analyzer like [WhoCrashed](http://www.resplendence.com/whocrashed).  It can tell you which device driver crashed the computer if that is the case.  For example, in my case it showed the Video Driver as the culprit, and even gave a plain English recommendation: `A third party driver was identified as the probable root cause of this system error. It is suggested you look for an update for the following driver: nvlddmkm.sys (NVIDIA Windows Kernel Mode Driver, Version 375.95 , NVIDIA Corporation)`:

```
On Sun 11/20/2016 9:32:54 AM your computer crashed
crash dump file: C:\WINDOWS\Minidump\112016-6000-02.dmp
This was probably caused by the following module: nvlddmkm.sys (nvlddmkm+0x3E15B0) 
Bugcheck code: 0x1000007E (0xFFFFFFFFC0000005, 0xFFFFF8088BBA15B0, 0xFFFF9980C97297F8, 0xFFFF9980C9729020)
Error: SYSTEM_THREAD_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED_M
file path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nv_dispi.inf_amd64_410e5247be0e5f00\nvlddmkm.sys
product: NVIDIA Windows Kernel Mode Driver, Version 375.95 
company: NVIDIA Corporation
description: NVIDIA Windows Kernel Mode Driver, Version 375.95 
Bug check description: This indicates that a system thread generated an exception which the error handler did not catch.
This appears to be a typical software driver bug and is not likely to be caused by a hardware problem. 
A third party driver was identified as the probable root cause of this system error. It is suggested you look for an update for the following driver: nvlddmkm.sys (NVIDIA Windows Kernel Mode Driver, Version 375.95 , NVIDIA Corporation). 
Google query: NVIDIA Corporation SYSTEM_THREAD_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED_M
```

Which suggests that I will downgrade the driver that was recently installed.

In my case, Windows 10 kept on updating the driver to the faulty one on its own, until I disabled that "feature" in `Device installation settings`:

[image]

Another thing to do is to uninstall recent Windows Updates which could be faulty.  For example, if you installed Security Update for Microsoft Windows KB3200970 then try to remove it.

Comment: Is there any risk in this method ? Anyway, It has been a few weeks now since my PC restarted the last time so I think the problem is solved, otherwise I will have to try your solution.

Comment: No risk.  All you're doing is disable automatic restart on crash so that you can see the crash details, and disable automatic driver updates which can install a faulty driver, as happened in my case with the NVidia driver.  You can always download the driver manually if and when you choose to.  Please upvote/accept the answer if you find it useful.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. As I said, the PC is running well now with no restarts, so I will keep it like this for now

Comment: Most likely your PC stopped restarting because the vendor of the faulty driver has issued an update that fixed the problem, and since your machine downloads updates automatically it was "fixed", but that doesn't mean it can not happen again with the next driver update.

Comment: Let's hope it won't happen again :)

Comment: Unfortunately the problem is back again, I checked the event viewer after restarting and that's what I got [link](http://imgur.com/a/TGWVz)

Answer (score 0):

All I did to fix mine from random error restarts was to turn my system restore protection on. System properties ---> system protection ---> click on drive to highlight ---> configure ----> click on turn on system protection. That's it.